# How can I print a String array with reflection with quotation marks in java

Tags: java, reflection

I am doing this to get a String array:

```
} else if (type == String[].class) {
    return Arrays.toString((String[]) field.get(this));
}
```

And the output I'm getting is like this:

```
[hello, null, null, Hoi, null, hola]
```

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
{"hello", null, null, "Hoi", null, "hola"}
```

The brackets are easy enough to change but I cant seem to get the quotes around the words

Comment: What do you mean by 'output'? Do you mean printing the array?

Comment: @Xinzz I'm using BufferedWriter to write it into a file but that shouldn't really matter right?

Comment: Yeah I mean if you use like `Arrays.toString()` it will leave out the quotation marks. Best to just iterate yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just iterate the array your self, and build the output with a StringBuilder.